# Java 8 Swing GUI for Spring.io

Tags: java, spring, swing, user-interface

I'm learning Spring.io and REST.
So my project at the moment, is to make a application in Swing with Spring.io, that pulls info from a RESTful service, and then show the info in the application.

I've been looking at JAX-RS (I think that's the name) but have been told that Spring.io, was much better to communicate with REST, and better handle. And since i need to learn Spring.io, I'm going with that.

So my question is, is there a GUI Addon/Extension for Spring.io where I can make a Swing application, just like there is for Eclipse?

It would be nice if it was drag/drop, just like the Eclipse Extension here:
[image: Eclipse SWING GUI Image]

Comment: And what do you actually expect to drag'n'drop?

Comment: spring will help you for IoC, Rest request... There is no GUI related components in spring.

Comment: @BranislavLazic - the app it self should not be drag/drop, its the making of the app i would like drag/drop, so i can pick a label, and place it where it should be.

JEY - can you explain what IoC is, or give me a link where i can read up on that? Thanks :-)